# Store boolean value in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

What is the type for a BOOL value in SQLite? I want to store in my table TRUE/FALSE values.

I could create a column of INTEGER and store in it values 0 or 1, but it won't be the best way to implement BOOL type.

Is there a way?

Comment: Although SQLite does not have boolean data type it supports [boolean literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223589/5070879)

Answer (score 462, accepted):

There is no native boolean data type for SQLite. Per the [Datatypes doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Comment: "INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value." I guess using 1 byte to store a BOOL isn't too bad.

Comment: Which is better in term of performance! true/false as strings or 0/1 integer?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar 0/1 most definitely. Strings are slower and take more space.

Comment: @joce Actually, integers 0 and 1 (as well as NULL) are encoded directly in row data type declaration. So it's zero bytes per boolean, if you only count the actual data storage, which is awesome. If you count per-column-per-row bookkeeping required by the file format though, *all* data types have an extra byte required, which is not awesome. :) (reference: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#record_format)

Answer (score 157):

In SQLite the best you can do is use the integers 0 and 1 to represent false and true. You could  declare the column type like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(mycolumn BOOLEAN NOT NULL CHECK (mycolumn IN (0, 1)));
```

Omit the `NOT NULL` if you want to allow `NULL` in addition to 0 and 1.

The use of the type name `BOOLEAN` here is for readability, to SQLite it's just a type [with NUMERIC affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname).

Note that [CHECK constraints](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst) have been supported since [SQLite 3.3.0](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_3_0.html) (2006).

Here are some example INSERTs that will work: (note how strings and floating point numbers are parsed as integers)

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(0);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(0.0);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1.0);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES("0.0");
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES("1.0");
sqlite> select mycolumn, typeof(mycolumn) from foo;
0|integer
1|integer
0|integer
1|integer
0|integer
1|integer
```

and some that will fail:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES("-1");
Error: constraint failed
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(0.24);
Error: constraint failed
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(100);
Error: constraint failed
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES(NULL);
Error: foo.mycolumn may not be NULL
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES("true");
Error: constraint failed
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo VALUES("false");
Error: constraint failed
```

Comment: Caution - if you set a `DEFAULT` you have to set it to `DEFAULT 0` or `DEFAULT 1` rather than `FALSE`/`TRUE` on some machines. Apparently some versions of Linux don't like that, although it works fine on Groovy.

Comment: A small addition. In ver.3.28.0, true/false inserts without quotes will be executed successfully:
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(true);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES(false);
Also true/false without quotes can be used in CHECK and in DEFAULT

Answer (score 95):

SQLite [Boolean Datatype:](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

You can convert boolean to int in this way:

```
int flag = (boolValue)? 1 : 0;
```

You can convert int back to boolean as follows:

```
 // Select COLUMN_NAME  values from db. 
 // This will be integer value, you can convert this int value back to Boolean as follows
Boolean flag2 = (intValue == 1)? true : false;
```

If you want to explore sqlite, [here is a tutorial](http://zetcode.com/databases/sqlitetutorial/).
I have given one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074865/set-flag-in-sqlite-database-in-android/9075127#9075127). It is working for them.

Comment: final line of code could just be "Boolean flag2 = (intValue == 1)"

Comment: I suggest `Boolean flag2 = (intValue != 0);`

Comment: or you can just do

     Boolean flag2 = (intValue > 0);

Answer (score 10):

using the Integer data type with values 0 and 1 is the fastest.

Answer (score 6):

Further to ericwa's answer. CHECK constraints can enable a pseudo boolean column by enforcing a TEXT datatype and only allowing TRUE or FALSE case specific values e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "boolean_test"
(
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
,   "boolean" TEXT NOT NULL 
        CHECK( typeof("boolean") = "text" AND
               "boolean" IN ("TRUE","FALSE")
        )
);

INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES ("TRUE");
INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES ("FALSE");
INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES ("TEST");

Error: CHECK constraint failed: boolean_test

INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES ("true");

Error: CHECK constraint failed: boolean_test

INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES ("false");

Error: CHECK constraint failed: boolean_test

INSERT INTO "boolean_test" ("boolean") VALUES (1);

Error: CHECK constraint failed: boolean_test

select * from boolean_test;

id  boolean
1   TRUE
2   FALSE
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use the four and five byte TEXT values ("TRUE","FALSE") and not the single byte INTEGER values (1, 0)?

Answer (score 6):

But,if you want to store a bunch of them you could bit-shift them and store them all as one int, a little like unix file permissions/modes.

For mode 755 for instance, each digit refers to a different class of users: owner, group, public.  Within each digit 4 is read, 2 is write, 1 is execute so 7 is all of them like binary 111.  5 is read and execute so 101.  Make up your own encoding scheme.

I'm just writing something for storing TV schedule data from Schedules Direct and I have the binary or yes/no fields: stereo, hdtv, new, ei, close captioned, dolby, sap in Spanish, season premiere.  So 7 bits, or an integer with a maximum of 127.  One character really.

A C example from what I'm working on now.  has() is a function that returns 1 if the 2nd string is in the first one.  inp is the input string to this function.  misc is an unsigned char initialized to 0.

```
if (has(inp,"sap='Spanish'") > 0)
  misc += 1;
if (has(inp,"stereo='true'") > 0)
  misc +=2;
if (has(inp,"ei='true'") > 0)
  misc +=4;
if (has(inp,"closeCaptioned='true'") > 0)
  misc += 8;
if (has(inp,"dolby=") > 0)
  misc += 16;
if (has(inp,"new='true'") > 0)
  misc += 32;
if (has(inp,"premier_finale='") > 0)
  misc += 64;
if (has(inp,"hdtv='true'") > 0)
  misc += 128;
```

So I'm storing 7 booleans in one integer with room for more.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the above equations using the following:

```
boolean flag = sqlInt != 0;
```

If the int representation (sqlInt) of the boolean is 0 (false), the boolean (flag) will be false, otherwise it will be true.

Concise code is always nicer to work with :)

Answer (score -5):

Another way to do it is a TEXT column. And then convert the boolean value between Boolean and String before/after saving/reading the value from the database.

Ex. You have `"boolValue = true;`"

To String:

```
//convert to the string "TRUE"
string StringValue = boolValue.ToString;
```

And back to boolean:

```
//convert the string back to boolean
bool Boolvalue = Convert.ToBoolean(StringValue);
```

Comment: @Craig McMahon suggests to use Integer instead: prime numbers represent true, non-primes represent false

Comment: I find that highly offensive, @Berik. The obvious solution is to render the word "TRUE" or "FALSE" onto an image and then save that in the database row as a JPEG-encoded BLOB. One could then read the value back using a simple feature extraction algorithm.