# Is there a boolean literal in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, boolean, literals

I know about the `boolean` *column type*, but is there a `boolean` *literal* in SQLite?  In other languages, this might be `true` or `false`.  Obviously, I can use `0` and `1`, but I tend to avoid so-called "magic numbers" where possible.

From [this list](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#data_types-boolean), it seems like it might exist in other SQL implementations, but not SQLite.  (I'm using SQLite 3.6.10, for what it's worth.)

Comment: Boolean literal != boolean data type. IMO it should not be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From section [1.1 Boolean Datatype](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) of the docs:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

So it looks like you are stuck with `0` and `1`.

Comment: I came here *after* reading that exact bit of the documentation, which, IMHO, is extremely ambiguous about whether `0` and `1` are somehow aliased with the identifiers `false` and `true`, respectively, by SQLite's SQL parser.

Comment: Sadly this answer doesn't respond to the question, which is not about the storage class/*column type* but the use of `TRUE` and `FALSE` *literals*, which are SQL-compliant as [per the Postgresql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-boolean.html).

Comment: @Lloeki - Sadly, you referenced Postgresql documentation for a SQLite question...

Comment: Sorry, I meant *ANSI* SQL-compliant, but couldn't find a definitive reference quickly enough so fell back to a note from the PostgreSQL doc. My comment started to turn like an answer so I cut short and transitioned into writing one that has the full run down and effectively gets to answer the actual question.

Comment: @Lloeki - SQLite is not ANSI SQL compliant with respect to booleans, though - their documentation is the definitive source. Along those lines, your link to the SQLite list of keywords is very useful to make it clear `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not supported.

Comment: @Lloeki SQLite now supports literals :) Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223589/5070879

Answer (score 33):

> *Is there a boolean literal in SQLite?*

As stated in [Justin Ethier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510670/5070879), SQLite does not have specific data type for boolean. But starting from [SQLite 3.23.0](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_23_0.html) it supports true/false literals:

> 2. **Recognize TRUE and FALSE as constants.** (For compatibility, if there exist columns named "true" or "false", then the identifiers refer to the columns rather than Boolean constants.)
> 3. Support operators IS TRUE, IS FALSE, IS NOT TRUE, and IS NOT FALSE.

```
SELECT true AS t, false AS f;

SELECT 'condition is true'
WHERE 1 IS NOT FALSE;

CREATE TABLE a (id INT, b BOOLEAN DEFAULT(TRUE));
INSERT INTO a(id) VALUES(100);
SELECT * FROM a;
-- id  b
-- 100 1

SELECT * FROM a WHERE true;
-- id  b
-- 100 1
```

**[dbfiddle.com demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/227aL7pDhR6QSckCm5JmdX/2)**

Answer (score 10):

> ***1.1 Boolean Datatype***
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

[**Docs**](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: I came here *after* reading that exact bit of the documentation, which, IMHO, is extremely ambiguous about whether `0` and `1` are somehow aliased with the identifiers `false` and `true`, respectively, by SQLite's SQL parser.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper IMO false and true doesn't exist in world of SQLite.

Comment: Yes, I figured so, based on the answers to this question, but the cited portion of the docs is extremely unclear about that IMO. It says boolean values are *stored* as the numbers `0` and `1`, respectively - and then indicates that those numbers match *false* and *true*. What are *false* and *true* there? Hints in natural language to readers, or constants/aliases understood by SQLite's SQL parser? As I said, it's very ambiguous the way it is written.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper for me it is clear. They mean that 0 is equivalent to `false` value of boolean logic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper they don't match, they represent - this is what they meant.

Comment: Doesn't say so. It could just as well be a `false` value understood by SQLite's SQL parser, it's just not clear. That's why reading that portion of the docs left me totally clueless and looking for some additional confirmation that there are no such constants `false` and `true` in SQLite, which is how I got here.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper clearness is matter of personal perception, I can't convince you that is is clearly written, for me personally it was clear. My logic was that if there is no thing as boolean datatype so that if true/false exist they must be integer constants. 10 seconds test can demonstrate that they are not constants/keywords. I actually don't know any language without boolean type and with boolean constants.

Comment: In some versions of C that do not have a boolean type, `define`-ing `TRUE` and `FALSE` [isn't unusual](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17010041/why-define-true-1-1-in-a-c-boolean-macro-instead-of-simply-as-1).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper C doesn't have bool by design. Some compilers may introduce pseudo-bool constants but it is bad idea imo, because no portability. Defining constant on your own is different thing from having it within language.

Comment: Some C compilers may introduce pseudo-bool constants, just as some SQL parsers may introduce pseudo-bool constants.

Comment: @Andrey C may not have an explicit boolean type, but it has booleans (i.e. whatever you put in an if condition, be it a comparison, integer, or result of a function call, is treated as a boolean because it can only have one of two effects), so it makes sense to have aliases to true and false. By the same token, SQLite doesn't have a boolean type, but it also has booleans, so it would make sense for a language designer to define aliases there, also. "Defining constant on your own is different thing from having it within language" Yes, but there are standard library defines.

Comment: @ParthianShot what you say can shorter be expressed as that SQLite supports boolean expressions.

Answer (score 9):

The question is explicitly not about the *column type* (i.e storage-wise) but the use of `TRUE` and `FALSE` literals (i.e. parser-wise), which are SQL-compliant as [per the PostgreSQL keywords documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (which happens to also include SQL-92, SQL:2008 and SQL:2011 columns in the reference table).

The SQLite documentation lists [all supported keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), and this list contains neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, hence SQLite sadly is non-compliant in that regard.

You can also test it easily and see how the parser barfs as it wants the token to be a column name:

```
$ sqlite3 :memory:
SQLite version 3.14.0 2016-07-26 15:17:14
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo (booleanish INT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo (booleanish) VALUES (TRUE);
Error: no such column: TRUE
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Sqlite client libraries sometimes suppress this error (WTF), but as you've shown, if you run it in the command-line `sqlite3` app, it doesn't like "true" or "false" literals.

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer as of SQLite version 3.23, as noted in Lukasz's answer.

Answer (score 5):

As everyone else has pointed out, SQLite does not support a specific boolean *storage* type, and the OP specifically acknowledges this fact. However, this is completely independent of whether SQLite supports boolean *literals and comprehensions*.

For anyone wondering, the answer is **YES**, since SQLite 3.23 you can do boolean comprehensions with the boolean literals `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and it will work how you expect.

For example, you can do:

`SELECT * FROM blah WHERE some_column IS FALSE;`

`SELECT * FROM blah WHERE some_column IS TRUE;`

and it will work how you expect if you are using `0` for false and `1` for true.

From my testing, here is how SQLite matches various values:

- Any non-zero NUMERIC, INTEGER, or REAL: `IS TRUE`
- Any zero NUMERIC, INTEGER, or REAL: `IS FALSE`
- A null value: `IS NULL`. Does not match `IS TRUE` or `IS FALSE`.
- Any TEXT that does not parse to a numeric value: `IS FALSE`. Even values like "t", "TRUE", "true", "True" still match `IS FALSE`
- TEXT that looks like a number (eg "0", "1", "5"): Behaves like NUMERIC, listed above.
- BLOB: Untested.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in sqlite for android, I can declare a Boolean column type with no error and its seems to work fine. I also tried defining the column as 'int' and storing java boolean values. I downloaded the db and confirmed I'm writing "true" in the column. I think it just works.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE a (b BOOLEAN DEFAULT(TRUE));` fails because it doesn't understand `TRUE`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Now you can https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223589/5070879 :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no boolean data type.  There are only 5 types, listed [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).  Integers can be stored with various widths on disk, the smallest being 1 byte.  However, this is an implementation detail:

> "But as soon as INTEGER values are
>   read off of disk and into memory for
>   processing, they are converted to the
>   most general datatype (8-byte signed
>   integer)."

Given that, it is not surprising there are no boolean literals.

Comment: On the flip side, SQLite supports datetimes, despite not being one of those five types, so this answer is inconclusive. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Answer (score -1):

There are only 5 datatypes supported in SQLite3.

From the Official SQLite3 doc.
 "Each value stored in an SQLite database (or manipulated by the database engine) has one of the following storage classes:

```
NULL. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value."
```

If you are going to store 1s and 0s, then SQLite wil use 1 byte if storage. Which is not bad.
Official Doc link :- http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: On the flip side, SQLite supports datetimes, despite not being one of those five types, so this answer is inconclusive. sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Answer (score -1):

You can use `BOOLEAN` when creating a table:

```
sqlite3 :memory:
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE test (mybool BOOLEAN);
```

But this is not a real datatype and on the SQL description of the table we will have something like this:

```
"mybool" BOOLEAN NOT NULL CHECK(mybool IN(0,1))
```

Basically we create an SQL constrain constrain that the value should be 0 or 1. And therefore using TRUE/FALSE will pop an error:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO test(mybool) VALUES (TRUE);
Error: no such column: TRUE
```

So, we can use the key word `BOOLEAN` but have to use 0/1 since it is not a "real" datatype.

When working with sqlalchemy we can use the datatype BOOLEAN without any problems

Answer (score -1):

SQLite has TRUE and FALSE literal as shown here :

https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/literal-value.html

(yeah, long time to respond :)

Answer (score -2):

SQLite doesn't have Boolean type, you should use INTEGER with 0 is false and 1 is true

Answer (score -3):

***BOOLEAN -> NUMERIC (Affinity)***

**Column Affinity**

SQLite supports the concept of type affinity on columns. Any column can still store any type of data but the preferred storage class for a column is called its affinity. Each table column in an SQLite3 database is assigned one of the following type affinities:
Affinity    Description

- TEXT This column stores all data using storage classes NULL, TEXT or
  BLOB.
- NUMERIC  This column may contain values using all five storage
  classes.
- INTEGER  Behaves the same as a column with NUMERIC affinity
  with an exception in a CAST expression.
- REAL Behaves like a column with NUMERIC affinity except that it forces integer values into floating point representation
- NONE A column with affinity NONE does not prefer one storage class over another and no attempt is made to
  coerce data from one storage class into another.

**Boolean Datatype:**

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

> @moiing-duck
>   *"On the flip side, SQLite supports datetimes, despite not being one of those five types, so this answer is inconclusive"*

**SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times.** Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as **TEXT, REAL,** or **INTEGER** values:

Comment: On the flip side, SQLite supports datetimes, despite not being one of those five types, so this answer is inconclusive. sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime

Comment: Well, that was aggressive.  Since you completely misunderstood my point, I'll clarify: The OP is not asking if sqlite has a boolean column affinity. The OP is asking if Sqlite understands 'true' and 'false'.  The fact that sqlite has built in functions for dates and times is proof that a focus on affinity is irrelevant to the question.  If he was asking if sqlite supports dates and times, the answer would be yes.