# Access Boolean Value form Sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I newly add a column to one of my data base table using following query.

```
alter table 'user' add column 'IsMarried' BOOL default 'false';
```

Once the database update done user 'jhon' has IsMarried status as 'true' in the database.

And then I write a sql query using Objective C to retrieve the jhon's married status as bellow.

```
BOOL married = [results boolForColumn:@"IsMarried"];
```

My problem is the boolean varible 'married' always return false;

Then I add follwing line to the code to check whether the correctness

```
NSString *strMarried = [results stringForColumn:@"IsPwdProtected"];
```

then strMarried return 'true' for jhon. Can some one tell me how to retrive the boolean value using
boolForColumn method

Comment: You're converting SQL text blobs to numbers and testing for Boolean values. Use numbers (0 is false, 1 is true)

Comment: There is no such method as `stringForColumn` in the standard sqlite3 framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOL isn't supported in SQLite, you have to stick with integers (0 and 1) to represent false and true respectively. More info on that here:
[Is there a boolean literal in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510652/is-there-a-boolean-literal-in-sqlite)

I'm not currently in front of a Mac so I can't test this but I imagine the following will get you want you want:

```
alter table 'user' add column 'IsMarried' INTEGER default 0;
```

If you then update your user 'jhon' to have married status of 1, I suspect your call to `boolForColumn` will return true.

Answer (score 0):

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

So you can use the below code

```
NSString *boolString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

BOOL married = [boolString boolValue];
```

Answer (score -1):

'false' and 'true' are strings.