# SQLITE3 How to quickly and efficiently query this?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to compare a local variable

```
currentTime = time.time()
```

with data in my table, under the AuthorID column, to see which value is bigger. Then, I will proceed to update the column 'Reminded' to True. My table is called reminderFormat.

This is how the Database looks: http://prntscr.com/gb9ay1

What is the best way to go about this? I believe I could specifically fetch FutureTime and store it as a variable, then compare it to currentTime. However, would there be a better option for this which is quicker and more efficient using a query?

Thanks

Comment: See [How to format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the best practice is to use a single SQL statement to update the records.

Since, [SQLite has no boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510670/1513933), you need to set the value **1** (instead of True).

For instance, the statement could be:

```
import time

st = "UPDATE reminderFormat SET Reminded = 1 " \
     "WHERE FutureTime <= {currentTime}".format(currentTime=time.time())
```

**EDIT: Demo**

Here is a demo:

```
import time
import sqlite3

records = [
    (20183740995, 1503330725.0, "testtt", 0),
    (20183740995, 1503330732.0, "testtt", 0),
    (20183740995, 1503331334.0, "testtt", 0),
    (20183740995, 1509999999.0, "testtt", 0),
    ]

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

# Create the table
con.execute("create table reminderFormat(AuthorID, FutureTime, Message, Reminded)")

# Fill the table
con.executemany("INSERT INTO reminderFormat(AuthorID, FutureTime, Message, Reminded) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", records)

curr_time = time.time()
con.execute("UPDATE reminderFormat SET Reminded = 1 WHERE FutureTime <= ?", (curr_time,))

# Print the table contents
for row in con.execute("SELECT AuthorID, FutureTime, Reminded FROM reminderFormat"):
    print(row)
```

You get:

```
(20183740995, 1503330725.0, 1)
(20183740995, 1503330732.0, 1)
(20183740995, 1503331334.0, 1)
(20183740995, 1509999999.0, 0)
```

Comment: See [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: @CL: Agree, but I don't know which client library used the OP, so…

Comment: Worked very well - thank you.
For some reason, If I remove the , in (curr_time,) I get an error.
Also, I needed to commit to the flle to get it to save.
Thanks

Comment: @smye parameters are passed by `tuple`. So, the trailing comma means this is a `tuple` singleton. Without a comma, it is a scalar.

Comment: @smye Anything else?

Answer (score -2):

In sqlite3 you can use a `Case` statement in query to check if your current time is less than or greater than the `AuthorID` for this your query in sqlite3 would be something like this:

```
select case AuthorID<Futuretime then 1 else 0 end from table;
```

This should provide you with `1` and `0` in the column without having to fetch time to python.