# How to convert Boolean Value to Int value using Sqlite in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, persistence, converters

Using `flutter` I have this model

```
  class Task {
  String color;
  String env;
  String id;
  String name;
  String description;
  bool isBuyIt;
  bool isOnBacklog;
 }
```

I am using `SwitchListTile` in order to change the boolean value of `isBuyIt` and `isOnBacklog`

```
SwitchListTile(
              activeColor: HexColor(task.color),
              title: Text("Do you have it?"),
              value: task.isBuyIt,
              onChanged: (bool value) {
                setState(() {
                  task.isBuyIt = value;
                });
              },
              secondary: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                onPressed: null,
                color: HexColor(task.color),
              ),
            )
```

I am using `sqflite: ^1.3.0` and as you know it does not [support bool value](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). I made the table like this way:

```
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnColor TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnEnv TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnDescription TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnisBuyIt INTEGER NOT NULL,
            $columnisOnBacklog INTEGER NOT NULL
          )
          ''');
  }
```

But I dont know how to convert `Boolean` value into `Integer` value. I dont want to change the model fields to `Integer` because `SwitchListTile`doesnt works with `INT` value

I guess `Check Constraint` would work.

Comment: you can use 1 and 0 instead of true and false. You just need to update `toMap` and `fromMap` methods

Comment: SQLite supports [boolean literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223589/5070879) - if it helps at all

Comment: @Tuqay that's good solution

Comment: @LukaszSzozda It works, can you post the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from [SQLite 3.23.0 literal true/false](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_23_0.html) are recognized and could be used.

> Recognize TRUE and FALSE as constants. (For compatibility, if there exist columns named "true" or "false", then the identifiers refer to the columns rather than Boolean constants.)

```
CREATE TABLE a (id INT, i BOOLEAN);
                                  
INSERT INTO a(id,i) VALUES(10,true);
INSERT INTO a(id,i) VALUES(20, false);

SELECT * FROM a;
```

**[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rci2HPoTw13zx2hPnQMvEd/0)**

Comment: I just changed ```$columnisBuyIt INTEGER NOT NULL,``` to ```$columnisBuyIt BOOLEAN NOT NULL,``` and it worked

Comment: @TuGordoBello Glad to hear I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).
i know three way that i know to do that
here is an example

if You want to convert boolean to int you can say   .

```
int flag = (boolValue)? 1 : 0;
```

and if you want to convert it back to bool you should say

```
Boolean flag2 = (flag == 1)? true : false;
```

in another way
Use the following ALTER statement -

```
ALTER TABLE CREATE_DB_TABLE ADD status boolean NOT NULL default 0;
```

Then you can use Cursor to get the required value and then convert to actual boolean -

```
flag=cursor.getString(0).equals("1")
```

or third one is which is similar to one above is

```
Boolean flag = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("flag")) == 1);
```

Comment: I was considered that solution as a last solution. I don't want to add validations like this and get dirty the code