# SQLiteException on some Android 9, 10 devices when using CASE, WHEN TRUE

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The following SQL statement works fine on my Android test devices (Android 13):

```
SELECT *
FROM portfolio
JOIN holdingCalculations
ON portfolio.uid = holdingCalculations.uid
ORDER BY calc_num_transactions = 0, CASE use_local_currency_for_totals WHEN TRUE THEN calc_total_change_percent_local ELSE calc_total_change_percent END DESC, portfolio.name COLLATE NOCASE
```

However after I've released my Android app to production, I'm seeing exceptions on some customer devices (Such as POCO F1 running Android 10, Galaxy S8+ running Android 9):

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: TRUE (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT *
FROM portfolio
JOIN holdingCalculations
ON portfolio.uid = holdingCalculations.uid
ORDER BY calc_num_transactions = 0, CASE use_local_currency_for_totals WHEN TRUE THEN calc_total_change_percent_local ELSE calc_total_change_percent END DESC, portfolio.name COLLATE NOCASE
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1229)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:703)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1865)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
       at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.kt:156)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidQuery.executeQuery(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:253)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidQuery.executeQuery(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:228)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver$executeQuery$2.invoke(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:149)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver$executeQuery$2.invoke(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:149)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver.execute(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:127)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver.executeQuery(AndroidSqliteDriver.kt:149)
       at com.squareup.sqldelight.db.SqlDriver$DefaultImpls.executeQuery$default(SqlDriver.kt:35)
```

My guess is that this sqlite syntax is not supported on some devices. Could this be an issue with the version of sqlite installed on those devices, and is there a backwards compatible way of writing this query?

Comment: Possibly related: [Is there a boolean literal in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510652/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang now yes but only since SQlite 3.23.0 and hence the issue that it works for 13 but not for 9 and 10 (only 11+ have an SQLite version high enough).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of true/false requires SQLite 3.23.0 or higher. Only since API 30 (Android 11) has the SQLite version been high enough (3.28.0).

Unless you are limiting the distribution to 11+, then you should use 0 for false and 1 for true.

You may wish to refer to:-

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#boolean_expressions

and

[Version of SQLite used in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)