# How to implement sorting in Room and how do I test it?

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm currently trying to implement sorting in `Room`. Here's my code:

Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY " +
        "CASE WHEN :isAsc = true THEN :field END ASC, " +
        "CASE WHEN :isAsc = false THEN :field END DESC ")
fun sortList(field: String, isAsc: Boolean?): Flow<List<Model>>
```

Repo

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun sort(field: String, isAsc: Boolean?):  Flow<List<Model>>{
    return dao.sortList(field, isAsc)
}
```

ViewModel

```
fun sort(field: String, isAscending: Boolean? = true) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repo.sort(field, isAscending)
}
```

As a side question, is my code possible? Can I make the order by field a parameter as well? I want to have only one function for sorting, if possible.

This is how I currently test it.

```
dao.insert(instance1)
//repeat this a couple of times

val tempLst = arrayListOf<Model>()
tempLst.add(instance1)
//repeat this the same times as the dao.insert

val sortedLst = tempLst.sortedBy { it.schedDate }

val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
val job = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
    dao.sortList("schedule_date", true).collect {
        assertThat(sortedLst).isEqualTo(it)
        latch.countDown()
    }
}
latch.await()
job.cancelAndJoin()
```

Now, I searched for how to test sorting but can't seem to find any. Is sorting testable? How do you test it? Also, for some reason, that test doesn't finish. I hope you can help me with that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is sorting testable?

Yes see below.

> Can I make the order by field a parameter as well?

Yes, BUT see below.

> How do you test it?

as below,

> Also, for some reason, that test doesn't finish.

your issue is probably because it is running an another thread. *again see below*

How I have tested you actual query:-

First created the DB code NOTE using `.allowMainThreadQueries`  AND without `Flow` as per :-

```
@Entity
data class Model(
    @PrimaryKey
    val modelId: Long?=null,
    val col1: String,
    val col2: String,
    val col3: String
)

@Dao
interface TheDAOs {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(model: Model): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY " +
            "CASE WHEN :isAsc THEN :field END ASC, " +
            "CASE WHEN :isAsc THEN :field END DESC ")
    fun sortList(field: String, isAsc: Boolean?): /*Flow<*/List<Model>/*>*/
}
```

- Note true/false removed as they were only introduced in more recent API's, they are not needed. see [SQLiteException on some Android 9, 10 devices when using CASE, WHEN TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75563013/sqliteexception-on-some-android-9-10-devices-when-using-case-when-true/75563198#75563198)

:-

```
@Database(entities = [Model::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getTheDAOs(): TheDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: TheDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /*<<<<<<<<<< FOR TESTING >>>>>>>>>>*/
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Then in an activity, coded:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: TheDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getTheDAOs()

        dao.insert(Model(modelId = 10, col1 = "ABC", col2="MNO", col3 = "XYZ"))
        dao.insert(Model(modelId = 20, col1 = "XYZ", col2="ABC", col3 = "MNO"))
        dao.insert(Model(modelId = 30, col1 = "MNO", col2="XYZ", col3 = "ABC"))

        for (m in dao.sortList("col1",true)) {
            Log.d("DBSORT_RUN1","ID is ${m.modelId} COL1=${m.col1} COL2=${m.col2} COL3=${m.col3}")
        }
        for (m in dao.sortList("col2",true)) {
            Log.d("DBSORT_RUN2","ID is ${m.modelId} COL1=${m.col1} COL2=${m.col2} COL3=${m.col3}")
        }
        for (m in dao.sortList("col1",false)) {
            Log.d("DBSORT_RUN3","ID is ${m.modelId} COL1=${m.col1} COL2=${m.col2} COL3=${m.col3}")
        }
    }
}
```

The result written to the log:-

```
2023-03-22 21:10:34.027 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 21:10:34.027 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 21:10:34.027 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC


2023-03-22 21:10:34.030 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 21:10:34.030 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 21:10:34.030 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC


2023-03-22 21:10:34.033 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 21:10:34.033 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 21:10:34.033 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC
```

**They have not been sorted as expected** (they are all the same)

However, perhaps consider:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY  " +
        "CASE WHEN :isAsc AND :field='col1' THEN col1 END ASC, "
        + "CASE WHEN NOT :isAsc AND :field='col1' THEN col1 END DESC, "
        + "CASE WHEN :isAsc AND :field='col2' THEN col2 END ASC, "
        + "CASE WHEN NOT :isAsc AND :field='col2' THEN col1 END DESC, "
        + "CASE WHEN :isAsc AND :field='col3' THEN col3 END ASC, "
        + "CASE WHEN NOT :isAsc AND :field='col3' THEN col3 END DESC "
)
fun sortListV2(field: String, isAsc: Boolean?): /*Flow<*/List<Model>/*>*/
```

Resulting in (when sortListV2 is used):-

```
2023-03-22 21:20:49.457 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 21:20:49.457 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC
2023-03-22 21:20:49.457 D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO


2023-03-22 21:20:49.460 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 21:20:49.460 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 21:20:49.460 D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC


2023-03-22 21:20:49.462 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 21:20:49.462 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC
2023-03-22 21:20:49.462 D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
```

*the expected results*

An alternative is to utilise an [**`@RawQuery`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery), which can be simpler BUT is not checked at compile time e.g.

```
@RawQuery
fun sortListRawQuery(query: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<Model>
fun sortListV3(field: String, isAsc: Boolean): List<Model> {
    var ascDesc = "ASC"
    if (!isAsc) ascDesc = "DESC"
    return sortListRawQuery(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT * FROM model ORDER BY ${field} ${ascDesc};"))
}
```

And using sortListV3 then :-

```
2023-03-22 22:01:14.133  D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 22:01:14.133  D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC
2023-03-22 22:01:14.133  D/DBSORT_RUN1: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO


2023-03-22 22:01:14.135  D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 22:01:14.135  D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
2023-03-22 22:01:14.135  D/DBSORT_RUN2: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC


2023-03-22 22:01:14.138  D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 20 COL1=XYZ COL2=ABC COL3=MNO
2023-03-22 22:01:14.138  D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 30 COL1=MNO COL2=XYZ COL3=ABC
2023-03-22 22:01:14.138  D/DBSORT_RUN3: ID is 10 COL1=ABC COL2=MNO COL3=XYZ
```

- Of course you can wrap the results in `Flow`s as required.

Comment: Oh, thanks for all the info. I'll try this out