# SQLite inserting bool value

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, boolean

I need to insert `BOOL` value into SQLite table. If you have any thoughts, or sample code please share.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store boolean value in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store boolean value in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Answer (score 10):

SQLite **can** recognize the BOOL as a type, however it is stored as an integer rightfully mentioned by Oli Charlesworth.

However using the BOOL keyword would still work:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable(
    isBool   BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
);

INSERT INTO YourTable (isBool) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO YourTable (isBool) VALUES (4);

SELECT * FROM YourTable;

isBool    
----------
1         
4
```

**4** would still be added to `YourTable`