# How to Add a Boolean Column in Android SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a table for my  `ContentProvider` using the following line :

```
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = 
  " CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME +
  " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
  " pid TEXT NOT NULL, " +
  " name TEXT NOT NULL,"+
  "number TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

It has 4 columns. Now i want to add a column with a boolean value of true/false. How can i add append/change this statement if i have to add a **boolean** column named **"status"**.

Comment: SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true). Check this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Comment: You mean to say , like `"status INTEGER NOT NULL,"` ???

Comment: go through this http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Thnx alot for quick help.

Comment: plz take a loot at this post,,,m waiting for answer for last 3 days, n i didn't even get a single comment...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24733444/how-to-use-two-cursors-and-cursorjoiner-in-loadermanager-in-android

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use something like this:

Create your table:

```
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = 
    "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME " + 
    " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
    "..." + " flag INTEGER DEFAULT 0)";
```

retrieve your value as:

```
Boolean flag = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("flag")) == 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about `CursorJoiner` and `LoaderManager`, since I don't use them. My suggestion is... can't you **JOIN** (or you wanted to do a **UNION**?) the two tables directly in a single query?

Comment: `CursorJoiner` actually joins two cursors. But, I need to call it via LoaderManager coz it queries the ContentProvider automatically. I need to reflect the changes at run time, and i cant afford to query again and again.

Comment: `joins two cursors` what about a single query that **UNION** (s) two SELECTs in a `single Cursor`? After all, you need only one cursor. So you'll get the same result with: **1** less Cursor and **0** CursorJoiner... => `SELECT ... UNION SELECT ...` (make sure that the fields are the same in both SELECTs. If a field is missing, add some `null AS myNonExistingField`)

Comment: In Select Statement, i need to mention the table, and unfortunately Phone Contacts doesn't allow to be as a table...as for as i know...

Comment: I see. But I'm convinced there's a way to query the contacts directly.  After all, it's a SQLite table...

Comment: May be, but at the moment i dnt know how

Comment: ... use Google intensively? ;)

Comment: OK, if you can wait a couple of days more (or 3), I'll try to study a solution to this issue.

Comment: Hay @Frank N. Stein, can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863038/avoid-swiperefresh-while-fastscrolling-in-android

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any clue with `fastScroll` and `SwipeRefresh`.

Comment: thanks, this method will also check, if the number odd or even, for any number

Answer (score 19):

As mentioned by M D,

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead,
>   Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Use the following ALTER statement -

```
ALTER TABLE CREATE_DB_TABLE ADD status boolean NOT NULL default 0;
```

Then you can use Cursor to get the required value and then convert to actual boolean -

```
flag=cursor.getString(0).equals("1")
```

You can use this flag to display on user screen.

Reference: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Well I would probably use `return c.getShort(index) == 1;` instead.

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately android sqlite does not support Boolean type and you should use Integer instead of it

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum Status{
        TRUE,FALSE;
}
static final String CREATE_DB_TABLE = 
  " CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME +
  " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +......
  " booleanColumn INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";
```

> //while inserting
>
> pass Status.TRUE.ordinal() values to database and
>
> //while retrieving
>
> cross check with the ordinal value for status

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite does not provide any class to store boolean values.

You can use `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`. You will then have to convert these values after retrieving them from your database.