# How to get List item data in bindView when clicking on RadioButton in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-radiogroup

I have a **`ListItem`** having a person name **`e.g. ABCD`** and a **`RadioGroup`** having two **`RadioButtons`**. In my `bindView()` when i click any of `RadioButton`, it should update the data whose name is **`ABCD`**. But its only updating the lastItem shown in my ListView. Here is my BindView() :

```
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            holder =  new  Holder();
            holder.stName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.stName);
            holder.stName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceContentProvider.STUDENT_NAME)));

            _id_ = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceContentProvider._ID));
            _name_ = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AttendanceContentProvider.STUDENT_NAME));


            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    switch (checkedId) {
                    case PRESENT:
                        values.put(AttendanceContentProvider.PRESENT, checkedId);
                        break;
                    case ABSENT:
                        values.put(AttendanceContentProvider.ABSENT, checkedId);
                        break;
                    case LEAVE:
                        values.put(AttendanceContentProvider.LEAVE, checkedId);
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                   String where = "((" + 
                            AttendanceContentProvider._ID + " LIKE '"+_id_+"') AND (" +
                            AttendanceContentProvider.STUDENT_NAME + " LIKE '"+_name_+"') AND (" +
                            AttendanceContentProvider._ID + " NOTNULL ))";
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().update(AttendanceContentProvider.STUDENTS_URI, values, where, null);


                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: And while `binding` the view, it definitely gives different data for different `ListItem`. Its just the problem for `RadioButton`.

Comment: You are creating a new view holder in `bindView()`? That seems really weird, what is the point of implementing the view holder pattern if you don't use it? And I guess something related to this is the source of your error. Show us more of your code.

Comment: I have solved this issue by making the cursor final and getting the position of cursor final too.

Comment: Thnx for your response. Always glad to have your response.