# Using a integer flag to save radio button status like a boolean

Tags: vb.net

I'm using this code to "convert" the status of a Radio Button to a integer in "boolean way"

```
If MyRadioButton.Checked Then
    cmdConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramMychoice", 1)
Else
    cmdConnection.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramMychoice", 0)
End If
```

The code works fine

Reading the answer of Muhammad Nabeel Arif in this link [Store boolean value in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

he uses

```
int flag = (boolValue)? 1 : 0;
```

But if I try something like

```
Dim flag As Integer
flag = (MyRadioButton.Checked)? 1 : 0
```

I get "option strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'boolean' to 'integer'"

Right, I understand and Visual Studio suggest something like
    flag = CInt((ProtocoloAutorizadaNoRadioButton.Checked))? 1 : 0

But I also get the error "The ? character cannot be used here"

**How can I use the solution of int flag = (boolValue)? 1 : 0 on VB.net?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using If

```
Dim flag As Integer
flag = if(MyRadioButton.Checked,1, 0)
```

[If Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx)

Also set explicit and strict to on to your project. (I recommend to set those two default to on in Visual Studio)

Comment: Clean solution. Also thanks for the tip about explicit setting