# SQLite default values to boolean column, not working as expected

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sqlite.net

I have one `SQLite` Table with following entity:

```
[Table ("employee")]
public class Employees
{
    [Column ("employee_id")]
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Column ("username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Column ("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column ("first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column ("last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column ("is_wah_allowed")] //Newly added Column
    public bool IsWAHAllowed { get; set; }  
}
```

When App starts, I am creating a Table.

```
conn.CreateTable<Employees>();
```

I want to add new boolean column with default value set to 0 - false in `SQLite` as it stores bool as 0 or 1.

I tried it following ways:

**Case 1 :**

```
[Column ("is_wah_allowed")] //Newly added Column
```

Output : This shows Null into DB Browser for SQLite

**Case 2 :**

```
[Column ("is_wah_allowed"), Default (false)] //Newly added Column
```

Output : This throws exception at conn.CreateTable(); - Can not convert from bool to int.

**Case 3 :**

```
[Column ("is_wah_allowed"), Default (value : 0)] //Newly added Column
```

Output : This shows False values into DB Browser for SQLite, instead of 0.
When server returns me data, I save/update them and then it shows them as 0 or 1 in updated rows, because server handle this as integer values.

I want to know :

Case 1 : Why it shows Null instead of 0 default value?

Case 2 : Why it throws exception?

Case 3 : Why it shows False instead of 0?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5):

There is no `boolean` exists in SQLite. Rather you store the `boolean` value in the database as int in SQLite. The values that you can use are 0 for false and 1 for true. When you go and select the int from the database. According to 0 & 1 you can right your `if` `else` block.

**Edit 1**

*Boolean Datatype*
SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

[SQLite data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

For more information visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite)

Comment: Isn't there a way to keep my Entity property type boolean and yet store 0, 1 values in SQLite? because I don't want to convert this type to integer.

Comment: Actually! You are using bool only while creating tables but it accept/fetch value as a 0 or 1 only. See my updated answer.