# Is there way to make sure that Sqlite3 will not commit other that intergers 0 and 1 to Boolean column

Tags: python, sqlite, boolean

I am new to coding. I am trying to create table with one column being Boolean with Sqlite3 and Python. Sqlite site states that:

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Is there way to make sure that when I am trying to commit an entry in the column it would not pass any other interger than 0 or 1? I fiugre that I can check this with a simple if statement (if interger > 1:), but I think it would be more beneficial if I could do that when I am creating the table so it would not be overlooked somehere else in my program, when it could potentialy make my table unusable.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843780/store-boolean-value-in-sqlite

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22186315/10498828